# Where should the logic for complex update validation live?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, crud

I'm having a discussion with my team and utilizing the Laravel framework.

Validating an update to an existing model's attribute that is a relationship requires a few DB calls to make sure it fits in the constraints.

My first thought is to create a custom validator, however, this would require queries within the validator. one to get the model being updated, one to get the relationship that exists and one to get the relationship that it would be updated too. This validator would also only ever be used for updating this one attribute on this one model.

Alternatively, this could be validated via an event, but I'm not sure the best place to keep that validation logic.

Any advice would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's custom validation rules were pretty much made for this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('account_id', 1);
        }),
    ],
]);
```

You can put whatever constraints you want one the query, it'll pass as long as at least 1 record is returned

Comment: But it just feels odd making one that will only ever be used the one time in that specific use case

Comment: That's what validation rules are for, most of them don't apply to more than one or two requests

Comment: And just ignore the overhead of querying the data multiple times?

Comment: If that's what it takes to validate the data, how else would get around that? What kind of validation are you trying to perform? Is it necassary to have all three of the original model, the old relationship, and the new relationship to perform the validation or could you get away with just comparing the relationship objects?

Comment: Comparing a state on each one and a few other things. I could simplify the query to a raw one without hydration to save some overhead, maybe even a short lived cache for it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit form validation placed namespace App\Http\Requests\Post;

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Post;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EditFormValidation extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required | max:150 | unique:posts,title,'.$this->request->get('id'),
            'description' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'This filed is required.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in controller

```
public function update(EditFormValidation $request)
    {
        $row = Post::find($request->get('id'));
        $row->update([
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'slug' => str_slug($request->get('title')),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'status' => $request->get('status')
        ]);

        $request->session()->flash('success_message', 'Post successfully updated.');
        return redirect()->to('post');
    }
```